# AngularJS: append partial instead of replacing current view

Tags: angularjs, view, partial

I wondered if it's possible to append a partial to the view, instead of replacing the previous one.

The usecase is as follows:

- I'm building a questionaire
- Upon starting the questionaire only 1 question is visible/in the DOM
- The answer of question 1 dictates what question 2 should be
- Upon answering question 1, question 2 gets appended to the DOM, under question 1
- If question 1 is changed, all other questions are reset/removed from dom, and a fresh, unanswered question 2 appears (under 1)

Maybe using one partial a question is not the way to go, in that case please let me know what the preferred method would be (vanilla/no-angular JS?)

Comment: You can use ng-include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a rough idea:

Given your app is in angularjs, you should be having all your questions inside a model in a controller:

```
$scope.questions = [
    {
        "question":"foo?",
        "options":["bar1","bar2","bar3","bar4"]
        "answer":2
    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
];

// initially show the 1st question
$scope.currentQuestIndex = 0;

$scope.currentQuestion = $scope.questions[$scope.currentQuestIndex];
```

And use the currentQuestion inside your view as:

```
<div>Question: {{currentQuestion.question}}</div>
```

When the user selects a correct answer, you could simply update the current question:

```
$scope.submitAnswer = function(){
    // check if the answer is correct
    if(isCorrect){
        $scope.currentQuestion = $scope.questions[$scope.currentQuestIndex + 1];
    }
}
```

This would dynamically update your view! Thanks to the **data-binding** feature provided by angularjs.

Comment: Ah thanks for the insight.. I'll probably change the approach slightly though. Using a model with all questions and display them according to some filter. Initially the filter only "passes" the first question, but as the user progresses through the questions, more get "unlocked".
I think I need a filter, because not all questions might be needed. Answering Q1 with 'yes' will produce a differtent Q2 then 'no'